# Render object items in text in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object

I have the following objects which I want to map and display as text.

console.log(props.items);

```
    Object {
      "p2": CartItem {
        "productPrice": 499,
        "productTitle": "Farm Feast Pizza",
        "productdescription": "Caramelized onion, yellow capsicum, black olives, cherry tomatoes, zucchini,  micro greens, feta and mozzarella cheese.",
        "productimageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/ZO82XbL.jpg",
        "quantity": 1,
        "sum": 499,
      }
Object {
  "p1": CartItem {
    "productPrice": 499,
    "productTitle": "Deluxe Veggie Pizza ",
    "productdescription": "Red peppers, broccoli, basil, cherry tomatoes, black olives, zucchini, jalapeno, micro greens, feta and mozzarella cheese.",
    "productimageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/NEbikrh.jpg",
    "quantity": 1,
    "sum": 499,
  },
}
```

I am trying to render the productTitle

```
<Text style={styles.title}>{props.items.productTitle}</Text>
```

but it is not rendering, kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: props.items.p2.productTitle maybe ?

Comment: data is dynamically generated so I cannot hard code key values

Comment: props.items[0].productTitle? try that

Comment: or if you resolving a then call with res or result in the second one take res[0] or result[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the array and map each item to a `Text` element

```
{props.items.map((item, index) => (
  <Text style={styles.title} key={index}>{item.productTitle}</Text>
))}
```

Here is the official react doc for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html